# Laravel watch poll not working with vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, browser-sync, laravel-mix

I am building a Laravel site running in a Vagrant box. I would like to enable live priview with Laravel mix. I have installed Browsersync with

```
npm install browser-sync browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.0.1 --save-dev --production=false
```

I added this to webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.browserSync('clever.laravel')
```

And my package.json includes the *watch-poll* option which is needed for using browsersync on Vagrant, according to the [documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/faq).

```
"scripts": {
        ...
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
}
```

But the `watch-poll` option does not have any effect, any changes are not reflected in the browser. How can I get browsersync / Laravel Mix Live Preview working with Vagrant?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `webpack.mix.js`:

```
    mix.browserSync({
        proxy: 'yourdomain.localhost',
        open: false,
        watchOptions: {
            usePolling: true,
            interval: 1
        }
    });
```